# Rails: limit Active Record joins query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

Given User `has_many` friends (self join) and `has_many` posts, return the count of all friends who have created at least one post.

If we set `user = User.first` then `user.friends` returns all users referenced as 'friends' to `user`:

```
user.friends.joins(:posts).count
```

returns the count of all posts associated with the user's friends.

I would like to return the count of *friends* who have at least one post association (perhaps by limiting the objects returned by the .joins query).

```
user.friends.map {|f| f.posts.first.present? ? 1 : 0}.sum
```

works but is slow.

Comment: Explain your Question clearly

Comment: @kamesh, if this revision is confusing, kindly elucidate what is unclear.

Comment: What are you trying to retrieve from your 2nd Query

Comment: "the count of all friends who have created at least one post."

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:
`user.friends.joins("INNER JOIN posts ON posts.user_id = users.id").select(:id).distinct.count`

There's even better way to make it with one request, but more detailed model description is needed to build that here.

Comment: Thanks Ivan! Have a look at my revised question and answer, how does that look to you?

Comment: Hard to tell. No clues what is `promotion_conversions` table.

Answer (score 0):

```
user.friends.joins(:posts).select("users.id").group("users.id").having("count(posts.id) > 1")
```